# How to initialise a custom class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, initialization

I'm very rusty with my objective C and genuinely can't remember how to initiate variables within a custom class upon creation.

Errors all on the `(id)init` line:

> *type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' (warning)
>
> *Type name requires a specifier or qualifier
>
> *Expected ';' at the end of declaration list

```
#import "Seat.h"

@implementation Seat
{
    (id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        player = NULL;
        position = -1;
        state = "empty";
    }
}

@end
```

Sorry if this seems simple, it appears its so simple I can't find much on it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a few things:

```
-(id)init // A minus says it's an instance method
{
    if (self = [super init]) { // You should check the return value of [super init]
        player = NULL; // Should this be nil?
        position = -1;
        state = "empty"; // Should this be @"empty"?
    }
    return self; // You need to return self
}
```

If `player` is an Objective C object, as opposed to a C pointer, it is more conventional to assign `nil` instead of `NULL`. Same goes for string literals: if `state` is `NSString *`, you should assign `@"empty"` to it.

Oh, and `@implementation` should not be enclosed in curly braces: the `@end` token is sufficient to find where the implementation block ends.

Answer (score 5):

On your right hand side utilities section , check the bottom half code snippet library . 
search for 'init' keyword . drag and drop the code

.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You've got one set of curly braces too many.  You also need to return self from init (and most people check for a non-nil result from `[super init]`).

```
@implementation Seat

(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      player = NULL;
      position = -1;
      state = "empty";
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```